# How prevent System.Xml.XmlDocument from escaping attributes values

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I've got an XML doc to deal with that contains attributes like:

```
<action name="foo -> bar">
```

If I make a simple:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(stInPath);
doc.Save(stOutPath);
```

The attribute string is escaped:

```
<action name="foo -&gt; bar">
```

Which is the very thing I'd want to prevent.

Do you know any way to do this (except than making a whole find&replace on the xml file afterward)?

**Edit:** It seems it's a legit behaviour, and that I don't have to worry about this (see Jon Skeet's answer)

Comment: I am frankly a bit surprised that the document loads at all.

Comment: but it does, and the attributes are preserved if you query these. Not that I reckon it's a good idea to do this, but it's a client's file.

Comment: Why would you not want to escape it? Escaping it is the correct thing to do. I'm not even sure having a " ->" in an attribute is valid xml.

Comment: @Fredrik: It's valid XML; ">" doesn't *require* escaping other than in a few specific situations. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/

Comment: @Vinzz: I tried it out; and it seems as if the characters are escaped already when loading the document.

Comment: @Jon: thanks for the info: I thought that both `<` and `>` were invalid.

Comment: You may try overriding the XmlTextWriter.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: From my point of view it was a genuinely bad design decision in XML to allow `>` unescaped in attribute values. Leads to sloppiness by those who know and misunderstandings by those who don't (like in this case). Especially since XML is so damn strict everywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need it not to apply that escaping?

Any normal parser should then apply the appropriate "unescaping" when it parses it. It sounds like you're trying to test the resulting XML document as a plain-text document, which is rarely a good idea. XML documents should almost *always* be fed to XML parsers in the next step, at which point this isn't an issue.

I don't know of any way of preventing the .NET XML libraries from doing this, and I'd be somewhat surprised if they had such a facility.

Comment: I'm indeed reading the xml file in a text editor (it's supposed to be human readable, isn't it?)

Well, it's then possible I'm seeing a problem where there's not at all. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Vinzz: Yes, XML is supposed to be human-comprehensible. But it's still *not* supposed to be treated as plain text. Don't let the fact that you can open it in a text editor distract you.

Comment: Unfortunately not all XML parsers are created equal.  I'm outputting an XML file from XmlDocument, and the Java-based third-party program that is importing the result does not like the escaped attribute value.

Comment: @EricJ.: I would *at least* ask the third party to fix their code then. You may need to work around it for the moment - but fundamentally this is a bug in their program, and should be treated as such.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Agreed, but I'm shipping next week and they won't fix it by then :-)  I did post a bug report, but also wrote a hack to post-process the file.

Answer (score 4):

> Which is the very thing I'd want to prevent.

Really? It isn't generally important at all whether that escaping is applied; the XML infoset for either is the same.

> I am frankly a bit surprised that the document loads at all.

`>` is a perfectly valid character to include in an attribute value. The only place `>` may *need* to be `&`-escaped in XML is in a `]]>` sequence in text content, due to an obscure and silly rule in the spec.

To avoid having to think about the problem, many XML serialisers habitually escape `>` anywhere in text content or attribute values.

The [Canonical XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n) specification specifies one particular way of serialising an XML document so the output can be compared as a simple string; for example it states exactly how attributes should be ordered. Canonical XML endorses `>`-escaping in text content, but it denies it in attribute values. So if you used a Canonical XML serialiser to output your document you'd get the result you expected for that particular value. (I can't guarantee it'd look how you want for other examples though.)

You can get a canonicaliser in .NET using [XmlDsigC14NTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.xmldsigc14ntransform.aspx) (or maybe XmlDsigC14NWithCommentsTransform), something like:

```
XmlDsigC14NTransform transform= new XmlDsigC14NTransform(false);
transform.LoadInput(doc);
Stream stream= (Stream) t.GetOutput(typeof(Stream));
// write stream to file
```